# Adding time of day attribute

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, attribute-table

I have a series of attribute tables that already have date-time, but I need to add a "time of day" attribute. Time of day is defined as one of the following four: "crepuscular_am," "crepuscular_pm," "diurnal," or "nocturnal". Crepuscular is within 60 minutes of sunrise or sunset. Diurnal is while the sun is up, nocturnal is while the sun is down. I have an .xls table with all the sunrise and sunset times, but I'm at a total loss about how to start tackling this complicated problem.

EDIT:

This is probably obvious, but the sun rises and sets at a different time each day.

EDIT2:

Here is an example of what my data looks like. Table 1 is the ARC attribute table where I need the "Time of Day," data. Table 2 is an excel spreadsheet with sunrise and sunset times.[image][image]

EDIT3:

I changed the format of Table 2, which, if I understood correctly, is what was suggested (this continues for 731 rows).

[image]

Comment: So you have two tables: one with a date-time and the second with the time of day and a specific time? And then you want to see what time of day the data in the first table corresponds to?  It may help future answers for a screen shot of both tables. Are you wanting this in ArcGIS as well?

Comment: I do not have any table with a "Time of Day." I need to generate that data based on the sunrise and sunset times. The data will be used in ARCMAP.

Comment: Thanks, that clears things up for me! I think first you're going to have to tackle getting both tables in a similar format for the dates. Your second table will have to be reworked to dates like in table one eg(dd/mm/yyyy). Or alternatively, have columns "sunrise" and "sunset" with (dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss). After that I think the best bet is a pythonic solution and perhaps an arcpy.cursor

Comment: I feel like this is perhaps two questions: 1)How can I format my data to do X, Y and 2) How can I calculate time of day based on date/time from Table 1 and Table 2 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You data needs to be worked on before you can do anything.

- Assign a unique day number in Table1. **Make sure the day value is unique for a given day**. If necessary, add the year and month somewhere. (20170101 for the 01/01/2017 for example, as suggested by @GISKid)
- Structure data in Table2 in a "database way", with **only one header column for each set of rows** and **usable date format fields**, with **one field day + 8 fields** : time of beginning and end of the time range for each time of the day.
- **Assign the same unique day in Table2** and make sure to join all Table2 type tables in only one unique table with unique day IDs and all your data for all year (for example)
- Use a **attribute join on the DAY field of both tables** to collect the start and end value for each line of your Table 1 file from Table2.
- **Query Table1** with something like this (1 for each time range of the day) :

  time > [start_time_crepuscular] AND time < [end_time_crepuscular]
- This will **select for each day the range of value in the time range**.
- **Update the TIME_DAY column** with the selected values

Comment: Why join on the day field? If the data spans over a few months then you'll have an incorrect join. Wouldn't it be better to join by dd/mm/yyyy? Or not join at all and use table 2 as a lookup table with a python solution?

Comment: Indeed ! I didn't see it was only up to 31. I thought it could go to 364 for example. That's why he needs to make sure the day field is unique, whatever the value. For example, for the first of january, he can use 20170101 as a unique join attribute and 01012017 as you suggest. Pyhton solution may be difficult for somebody who doesn't master python :) I think it can be done without. I edited my answer

Comment: All I know is date/times can be a real pain in the ass, so getting the formatting correct is important! +1

Comment: You're right ! I edited the answer to be more precise in case he has more than one table for one month.